# R: Plotly aspect ratio with small multiples / subplots

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly

I've posted this [as an issue on Github](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1288) two weeks ago. Since it's apparently ok to repost the question "[*if the project maintainers don't respond in a reasonable amount of time*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256647/4139249)", I'll post the question here.

I would like to create small multiples **with a fixed aspect ratio**. However, only some plots retain the correct aspect ratio. From what I gathered, setting a fixed aspect ratio with plotly is done as follows: `layout(yaxis = list(scaleanchor = "x"))`. Consider the follwing example:

```
library(purrr)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:5,25),
  y = rep(1:5,25),
  g = sort(rep(1:25,5))
)

plots <- df %>%
  split(.$g) %>%
  map(function(x){
    plot_ly(data = x, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter",mode = "lines") %>% add_lines()
  })

small_multiples <- subplot(plots,nrows = 5) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(scaleanchor  = "x")) %>%
  hide_legend()
```

If I plot `small_multiples`, only the first plot (row 1, column 1) has an aspect ratio of 1. The other have an arbitrary aspect ratio.
[image]
Here's the link to the interactive version of this plot: https://plot.ly/~rata_zhaw/1/

Interestingly, if I choose the option `shareX = T` in `subplot()`, the entire first column has the correct aspect ratio. Nothing changes if I choose `shareY = T`
[image]

And here's the link to the interactive version of the second plot: https://plot.ly/~rata_zhaw/3/

If I plot any of the plots individually, the aspect ratio is correct:

```
plots[[10]] %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(scaleanchor  = "x")) %>%
  hide_legend()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
small_multiples <- subplot(plots,nrows = 5) %>%
  layout(scene = list(aspectration=list(x=1,y=1))) %>%
  hide_legend()
```

[image]